# Tracking the success and failure of product download

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to track the complete/success and failure of product download for my ecommerce site.i m using asp.net handler which i called throuh jquery ajax.i wrote a code. but the downoad dialog box is not popped up and i still don't know the success and failure statistics.i need to update my databse based  on the returning json data (true for success/false for failure) from asp.net handler .Anyone help me out. The link i referred is

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/article.php/c17133/Tip-File-Download-in-ASPNET-and-Tracking-the-Status-of-Success-or-Failure-of-Download.htm

Comment: If this is so you can limit the number of download attempts - seeing as it's trivial to copy a downloaded file, I don't see the point in that. There are many errors that can happen on client side that the server can not catch (like "disk full" or write errors). I would just activate the download for a certain time (like, 24 hours) and not do any success checking.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Assuming Download() is a thread 

Private void DownLoad()
{
    try
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
        {  
           //Your code   
           Session["CurrentStatus"] = "SUCCESS"; //you can set download percentage here
        }
       Session["CurrentStatus"] = "COMPLETE";
    }catch()
    {
         Session["CurrentStatus"] = "FAIL";
    }
}


From Your UI you will fire an asynchronous event using PageMethod i.e

function GetCurrentThreadStatus()
{
       //You can use JQuery Ajax here
       //PageMethod is just an alternative
       PageMethods.GetThreadStatus(function(status){
           // success
           if(status=="COMPLETE")
           {
                //Update DB :: success
           }
           if(status=="FAIL")
           {
                //Update DB :: fail
           }
       });
}
Code Behind : C#

[WebMethod]
public static string GetThreadStatus()
{
     return  (string)Session["CurrentStatus"];
}
```